# WP_Query sorting by number with first some text in product title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I like to sort a WP_Query by product title and where the last characters of the product title are numbers. So it should be sorted by the last numbers.

Example products:

Mango’s Mates – 219

China Chun Mee – 301

Red Winter Punch – 428

My WP_Query so far that is working without the sorting:

```
 $argscat = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',



        );


        $all_categories = get_categories($argscat);

        foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {



            if ($cat->name != 'Thee') {
                $params = array('post_type' => 'product', 'limit' => -1, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post__not_in' => $numbersProductHidden, 'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'id',
                        'terms' => $cat->term_id,
                        'parent' => 1
                    ),
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                            'field' => 'name',
                            'terms' => 'exclude-from-catalog',
                            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                        ),
                    )
                ),

                );

                $loop = new WP_Query($params);
```

$loop should give the sorted result by numbers at the end of the product title

Comment: Is the format ALWAYS `– 219` is that an &mdash; ? and can it be more than 3 numbers?

Comment: Yes , the format is always a "hyphen with three numbers". It's not html mdash.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do what you want to do with PHP... I think you should be able to adapt this to suit your needs.  What you could do, is make an array with your initial results, and set the array key for that array to be the number that is at the end of your title.  Then use `ksort` and loop through the new array in the updated order.

```php
 // Example of results as an array.
 $results = array('China Chun Mee – 301', 'Mango’s Mates – 219' , 'Red Winter Punch – 428');

 // Loop through your initial results and create new array where the number at the end is the array key.             
 foreach ($results as $value){

     $number[substr($value, -3)] = $value;
 }   

 // sort your array on Key               
 ksort($number, SORT_NUMERIC);

 // Loop through new array and output your results in numerical order
 foreach ($number as $result){
     echo $result . '<br>';
 }
```

result from above is:

```
Mango’s Mates – 219 
China Chun Mee – 301 
Red Winter Punch – 428
```

Comment: I know howto bring the result from WP_Query to an array but I have to get it back to WP_Query object of otherwise the rest of the php codes breaks totally. I will have a look to get it back to an WP_Query

Comment: I don't understand your problem.  Can you look at your question and maybe revise it?